# Play Button on a Video Editing program I'm creating not working

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'm creating a video editor and it's going well so far. I just need to figure out a way of playing the video frames I have stored in an array and displaying them on a label. This is what I've tried so far, it doesn't work as expected. The video frames do not playback, instead the label displays only the last frame.

I'm just wondering where I'm going wrong or do I need to take a completely different approach to playing these frames.

Frames are captured by a JavaFX ImageView (originally a BufferedImage)

```
 @FXML
public void playButton() {
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {

        final int iFinal = i; //Workaround to allow i value to work in inner class

        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (1000 / frameRate));
                    previewBoxLabel.setGraphic(imageList.get(iFinal).getImage());
                    System.out.println("Play");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: "_it doesn't work sadly_" You are going to have to elaborate a bit more on what exactly isn't working. Errors, exceptions, incorrect output?

Comment: @Takendarkk Incorrect output, sorry. Video frames do not play. It just skips to the end frame and outputs that.

Comment: Is that surprising? For each image, you start a background thread. Each thread runs concurrently (which is the point of a thread...). All the threads wait for the same amount of time, then update the label to display the image (which, incidentally, you shouldn't do in a background thread). Since they all run at (almost) the same time, they all wait for (almost) the same time period, and all finish at (almost) the same time.

Comment: Damn.. that indeed does seem nonsensical. @James_D I wanted to run a thread which would output a frame then wait a small amount of time then output the next frame till it's updated every frame and gives an illusion of a video playing via the label.. 

The implementation didn't so much go that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
@FXML
public void playButton() {
        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                for (final ImageView image : imageList) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            previewBoxLabel.setGraphic(image);
                        }
                    });

                    Thread.sleep((long) (1000 / frameRate));
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: JAMES D!!!! OMG! It works :) I had to change the for loop as it was an array of tableDataModels (custom type). But man, thanks A LOT dude. I was bummed down about this problem all day. Seriously man, such a breakthrough. 

Thanks again and have a nice day/night :P